# Windows Server 2008r2 User Mapped Drives disconnect when GPO Mapped Drives are in effectg

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, mappeddrive

I am trying to find out if a user can map  their own drives and have them stay in place when they are subject to GPO mapped drives.

The GPO that is in place will Map a drive which is assigned Q and all folders are controlled by group membership from top level of Q down.

When my users log on, they loose all of their own mapped drives due o the GPO applying Q with the Update action. Is there a way I can have my users be able to map their own drives but also push the GPO mapped drive at the same time?

---

I have the action set as update rather than create, users can setup their own drives and they do stay in place when you remove the login script that someone else has place in their account profiles.

Comment: Are you using Group Policy Preference items to map the drives? If so, what `Action` is specified for the drive mapping?

Comment: Please use the `edit` button to add information to your question.